# threading concepts in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am intermediate in java. I am working with a company quite new to company, they have asked me to take session on "threading concepts in java with real example" as I don't have hands on on threading I can just prepare slides hoe threads can be implemented using `Thread` class or `Runnable` interface.

Can anybody please help me out with real scenario of threads and its implementation?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend Brien Goetz' "Java Concurrency In Practice".  It talks about features added to the JDK above and beyond Thread and Runnable that will make your life better.

In 2016 it's a better idea to dig into the `java.util.concurrency` package and JDK 8 lambdas and parallel stream.  No one should be trying to write multithreaded code with raw `Thread` unless they know what they're doing.  We've been given better abstractions - use them.

Comment: +1: Best response to the employer's task is to question whether a few slides on implementing `Thread` and `Runnable` is the right place to start for multithreading.  A few slides on JCiP and `Executor`, `Callable` and friends will be much more useful.

Comment: -1: I think "Java Concurrency In Practice" is overwhelming for a new developer. After reading the question I debated my self if I should be suggesting this book.

Comment: I agree that it's a lot, but I wonder if turning a neophyte loose with just Thread, Runnable, and synchronized is a good idea.  I thought that being aware would be worthwhile, even if was advanced.

Comment: "Java Concurrency In Practice" is indeed a difficult book, but if you can't follow it, you don't have the skills to do proper, safe multithreaded programming.

Comment: Agree, the Goetz books is advanced. The Sun, ahem Oracle tutorial on threading is probably a good place to start with perhaps a longer term goal to read the book (it is rather awesome after all)

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably start with Sun's (now Oracle's) excellent documentation on [concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

As an example, you can create something like a banking application where you have a shared data structure (accounts), and you have multiple threads operating on the account (performing withdrawals and deposits).

Answer (score 1):

The questions is too generic to answer but here are few details. Threads are used to run multiple things in parallel (in theory only it is based on lot of other factors like num of cpus, no of cores etc etc). Multi-threading has gone through lot of improvements in JDK since its inception. You can read the tutorial here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 1):

A real life example can be a telecom application SCP (service control point), that receives lot of requests , (in order of 400 in a sec). The application that handles the request employs a master-slave configuration. There is a thread pool, each thread of which is waiting for a signal to run.

The master thread, receives the request, the request data is posted in some object, that the thread functions reads, and then the thread is signaled to run. When the processing is finished the worker thread is returned to the thread pool.

There can be a flag, that informs about the status of the thread for example, busy, idle, bad etc.